# Writing a python function from a data file (csv) that outputs the string associated with an integer

Tags: python-3.x

I am comparing baseball statistics between players on a roster. My data is organized in rows that hold the players name, batting average, games played, amount of home runs, etc. The columns are organized by batting average, games played, amount of home runs, etc.
I split the data by columns, but now I want to create a function that finds the player with the most home runs for that season.
I was able to create a function (max) that can find the largest number from the list of home runs, but I want it to output the players name instead of just the number of home runs? Is there a way to do this or should I have split the data differently?

```
# importing csv file

import csv
text = open("yanks.csv").read()

# splitting rows

for row in text.split("\n"):
    columns = row.split(",")
    players = columns[0]
    year = columns[1]
    games_played = int(columns[2])
    home_runs = int(columns[3])

# Function to find max amount of home runs in a list
def most_hr(list):
    max = 0
    for i in list:
        if i > max:
            max = i
    return max
```

Now I want to get the player's name as output instead of the number of runs.

Comment: *"I was able to create a function (max)"* please post the code you're saying you've tried, as well as some sample input and output.

Comment: def most_hr(list):
    max = 0
    for i in list:
        if i > max:
            max = i
    return max

this will output "52", but I want it to output "Aaron Judge"

Comment: Please include this in the text body of your question so it can be properly formatted. Also, please provide a sample input.

Comment: okay just added the code

Comment: @AllyF were you able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head and without seeing your csv file, make the function that you have done return the largest number from the list and pass it to a function similar to this:

```
def getPlayer(homeRuns):
    with open('statistics.csv', 'r') as mycsv:
    reader = csv.reader(mycsv, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if row[x] == homeRuns:
            print(row[y])
```

In the above you need to change the x in `row[x]` for the column number that holds the home runs and the y in `print(row[y])` for the column number that holds your player name

Comment: I am getting an error code for row[5] = list (that = is an invalid syntax)

Comment: another error code:
for row in reader:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: @AllyF could you update your original post and include the code where you read the csv file?

Comment: In Python 3, you should open csv files in text mode.

Comment: @AllyF juanpa.arrivillaga is right. I changed the code, just change 'rb' for 'r'

Comment: Should I change the whole file to txt?

Comment: @AllyF No, just take the value that you get in the max function and pass it to my code above, it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to define your own `max` function. The builtin `max` takes a `key` keyword argument, you can use this to find the row with the highest value for a certain column, and then extract the name column.

```
PLAYER_NAME = ... # integer index of the player_name
HOME_RUNS = ...   # integer index of the number of home runs a play has

def home_runs(player):
    """
    Return the number of home runs for a given player by the 
    number contained in the HOME_RUN column.
    """
    return int(player[HOME_RUNS])

def player_name(player):
    """
    Get the name column from a player row.
    """
    return player[PLAYER_NAME]

def player_with_most_runs(rows):
    """
    Get the name of the player with the most home runs.
    """
    best_player = max(rows, key=home_runs)
    return player_name(best_player)
```

Then you can pass the rows from the csv reader into `player_with_most_runs`, and it will return the name of the player.

```
with open('stats.csv', 'r') as stats_file:
    player_records = csv.reader(stats_file)

best_player = player_with_most_runs(player_records)
```